# How To Implement Peer To Peer Text Chat with WebRTC and PHP on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, webrtc, p2p, shared-hosting

I've seen this example with shared hosting and PHP.

https://github.com/nielsbaloe/webrtc-php

It shares audio/video peer-to-peer, supposedly. Supposedly it does so even on shared hosting, and supposedly, once the connection is established, it works peer-to-peer. How could I modify this to send text chat messages, instead of audio and video?

> **EDIT**: In hindsight, this is probably not a good idea. Even if one pulled off peer-to-peer in a many-to-many situation, it isn't ideal because the expectation of text chats is that you can at least see the last 50-100 messages and not start fresh each time. That requires synchronized state management for all the peers at once, and there's no way to do that without a central server. And if that's the case, then WebRTC is not the best solution at all. Instead, utilize ordinary AJAX and implement any kind of simple server-side state management, such as RAM files, shared memory APIs (memcached, for instance), database tables, files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create a `datachannel` where you can send text data on peer-to-peer RTCPeerConnection.

You can take a reference from [here](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/data-channels)

Comment: What I dont understand is how to make the break from the example given where it does a video and audio transfer, to using RTCDataChannel.

Comment: the example that you've shared seems to be written for video/audio only. You need to add few lines of additional code which works like this ---- Create a new RTCPeerConnection, Exchange offer, answer and candidates to make a peer-to-peer connection, Create a datachannel

Comment: Right, but without NodeJS (which most of the server-side examples are based on unfortunately) because I use PHP, and without the ability to do WebSockets (shared hosting, so I need to use SSE / EventSource instead), all I have is that code from nielsbaloe to go on, and I'm stuck in trying to see where I changed it in order to do an RTCDataChannel. Nielsbaloe has figured out the way to use PHP + SSE/EventSource instead of NodeJS + WebSockets for the signalling step. However, I don't know the other technique on moving from the signalling step to the RTCDataChannel.